# White and Black chess pieces

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

The following works when I use the pro version of font awesome, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

I decided to use `class="fa fa-chess-pawn"` for black pieces and `class="far fa-chess-pawn"` for white pieces.

Q: Am I missing something obvious? Is there something I should use to differentiate between white and black pieces?

```css
.row {
 min-height:90px;
}
.col-1 {
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 border-right:1px solid black;
}
.left {
 border-left:1px solid black;
}
.top {
 border-top:1px solid black;
}
.card-body {
 font-size:72px;
}
.gray {
 color:white
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-queen"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-king"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fa fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-queen"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-king"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="far fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-Voup2lBiiyZYkRto2XWqbzxHXwzcm4A5RfdfG6466bu5LqjwwrjXCMBQBLMWh7qR" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to show the white chess pieces using Font Awesome Free?

Comment: As another note, the `fa` class name was deprecated in Font Awesome 5; its equivalent is `fas` (for the solid styling). https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#styles-and-prefixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work with the free version of font awesome: Add a "white" class to the parent (draggable container) and change `far` to `fas`:
As Chris Forrence mentioned: I'd suggest to change "fa" to "fas" (since "fa" is deprecated)

```css
.draggable.white {
    color: #fff;
}
.row {
 min-height:90px;
}
.col-1 {
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 border-right:1px solid black;
}
.left {
 border-left:1px solid black;
}
.top {
 border-top:1px solid black;
}
.card-body {
 font-size:72px;
}
.gray {
 color:white
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-king"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 left">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark left">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-king"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-bishop"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 bg-dark">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
    <div class="draggable white">
     <i class="fas fa-chess-rook"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-Voup2lBiiyZYkRto2XWqbzxHXwzcm4A5RfdfG6466bu5LqjwwrjXCMBQBLMWh7qR" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Only thing I'd suggest is to change "fa" to "fas" (since "fa" is deprecated)

Comment: Yeah, that's what recreational programming does to you late at night. I missed the obvious.